# Использование git дома и на работе

Tags: git, github

Я новичок по git.
Использую gitHub -как промежуточное звено, работаю в одной ветви (master). 
Периодически сталкиваюсь с проблемами, вроде конфликтов или вставок в рабочие файлы записей -  <<<<<<< HEAD ======= >>>>>>>

```
$ git pull
Auto-merging index.html
Auto-merging css/main.css
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in css/main.css
Removing README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git push
To https://github.com/loremIpsum/loremIpsum.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/loremIpsum/loremIpsum.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git merge
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Я создал репозиторий, затем склонировал будучи на работе уже с gitHub, стал менять код, выполнять стандартные команды, затем снова "пушить", чтобы продолжить дома,  но результат на лицо.
В чем моя ошибка? Как правильно организовать последовательность выполнения команд или может быть что-то ещё?

Comment: Читайте сообщения, что вам выводит `git`. Они осмысленные и полезные.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перед тем как что-то изменять в локальном репозитории на домашнем компьютере, вам над синхронизировать (обновить) свой локальный репозиторий.

Команда `git fetch [remote-name]` сходит в удаленный репозиторий `remote-name` и заберет для вас, все чего у вас нет. Т.е. теперь ваш локальный репозиторий полностью соответствует удаленному и конфликтов быть не должно.

После этого можете менять коммитить и пушить, но на работе надо так же сделать `git fetch [remote-name]`, чтобы изменения удаленного репозитория, сделанные дома, перенеслись на репозиторий на работе.

1. git fetch [remote-name]
2. Меняем что хотели
3. git commit ...
4. git push